# How to count sequences of repeated numbers in Python sequences?

Tags: python, sequence

I want to count how many times small sequences of adjacent repeated
number different from zero occurs in a given sequence. Let three sequences:

```
seq1 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
seq2 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
seq3 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The sequence `seq1` has 3 small sequences: `[1, 1]`, `[2, 2]`, and
`[3, 3, 3]`; the sequence `seq2` has 2 small sequences, both `[1, 1]`
separated by 0; and the sequence `seq3`, has 4 small sequences: the
first `[1, 1]`, `[1, 1, 1]`, `[2, 2]`, and the second `[1, 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
for k,g in groupby(seq1):
    if k != 0:
        print list(g)
...         
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 3, 3]

for k,g in groupby(seq2):
    if k != 0:
        print list(g)
...         
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
```

I think you can do the counting now. :)

Comment: Probably the best solution for this problem. Would take more memory in case of longer "series", though.

Comment: Thanks. I put in a single line: `len([k for k, g in itertools.groupby(seq1) if k != 0])`